# Tomcat7 restart issue using batch file

Tags: batch-file, tomcat7

I have written batch file to stop and start tomcat server but when server has huge load sometime if fails. Below is the script for restart-

```
@echo off

set current_date = %DATE%
echo Stopping Apache Tomcat service on   + %DATE%  >> restart.log
net stop tomcat7 >> restart.log 
net start tomcat7 >> restart.log
```

Below is the log I am getting on failed restart-

```
The Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 service could not be stopped.

The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later.
```

Should I use time lag between stop/start or should go for force kill server(if there is anything like this)

Comment: don't need lag between as `net start/stop...` doesn't return until the service is started/stopped. Maybe your service has dependencies or doesn't support stop? In the later, test if `sc query tomcat` says if it can be stopped, `sc qc tomcat` can tell you its dependencies (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If service is not stoppable you may try

```
@echo off

set "current_date=%DATE%" & rem not used!!

>>"restart.log" (
  echo Stopping Apache Tomcat service on %DATE%
  rem try to stop service. If failed (||) then kill process
  net stop tomcat7 2>&1 || (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=2 skip=3" %%i in (`tasklist /FI "services eq tomcat7"`) do (
      echo Failed to stop. Killing process Id %%i
      taskkill /PID %%i /F >NUL 2>&1
    )
    rem wait 1.5 second
    ping 1.1.1.1 -w 1500 -n 1 >NUL
  )
  net start tomcat7 2>&1
)
```